# Haskell Data.Decimal for rounding issue?

Tags: haskell, rounding

I would like to create a list of all the real numbers between 1.0 and 2.0 in two-decimal-place increments. This

```
dList = [1.00,1.01..2.00]
```

however, creates float run-on problems

```
dList = [1.0,1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05,1.06,1.07,1.08,1.09,1.1,1.11,1.12,
1.1300000000000001,1.1400000000000001,1.1500000000000001, ...
```

To remedy this I found what I thought was a function in `Data.Decimal` namely, `roundTo`. I was hoping to eventually run this

```
map (roundTo 2) [1.1,1.2..2.0]
```

and get rid of the float run-on, but it produces a giant error message. [This page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Decimal-0.5.1/docs/Data-Decimal.html) is for this beginner undecipherable. And so I'm trying to do this with an `hs` file loaded at a ghci REPL. This is the code

```
import Data.Decimal

dList :: [Decimal]
dList = [1.00,1.01..2.0]

main = print dList
```

and it produces

```
Could not find module ‘Data.Decimal’
```

Lost, I am....

Comment: `Could not find module` means you need to install the relevant package, because it does not come standard with the compiler.

Comment: You should probably be using [`Rational`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Rational) unless you intend to be doing lots of calculation.  But if you are, `Data.Decimal` is even worse.

Comment: Actually, you should clarify if you care about rounding error or printing values.  Because if all you care about is printing values, you should focus on `Double -> String` conversion, not floating-point error.  Things like [`showFFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showFFloat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer to your specific float problem

By far the simplest option in this case is

```
[n/100 | n<-[0..200]]
```

or variations on the same idea:

```
map (/100) [0..200]
(*1e-2) . fromIntegral <$> [0 .. 200 :: Int] -- (*) is more efficient than (/),
                                             -- but will actually introduce rounding
                                             -- errors (non-accumulating) again
```

No need for any special decimal library or rational numbers.

The reason this works better than the `[x₀, x₁ .. xe]` approach is that integers below 2<sup>52</sup> can be expressed exactly in floating point (whereas decimal fractions cannot). Therefore, the range `[0..200]` is exactly what you want it to be. Then at the end, dividing each of these numbers by 100 will still not give you *exact* representations of the hundredths you want to get – because such representations don't exist – but you *will* for each element get *the closest possible approximation*. And that closest possible approximation is in fact printed in `x.yz` form, even with the standard `print` function. By comparison, in `[1.00,1.01..2.0]` you keep adding up already-approximate values, thereby compounding the errors.

You *could* also use your original range calculation in exact rationals, and only then convert them to float<sup>★</sup> – this still doesn't require a decimal library

```
map fromRational [0, 0.01 .. 2]
```

Rational arithmetic is often an easy fix for similar problems – but I tend to advise against this, because it usually scales badly. Algorithms that have rounding problems in floating-point will more often than not run into *memory* problems in rational arithmetic, because you need to carry an ever-growing range of precision through the entire calculation. The better solution is to avoid needing the precision in the first place, like with the `n/100` suggestion.

Also, arguably the `[x₀, x₁ .. xe]` syntax is a broken design anyway; integer ranges have far clearer semantics.

Note also that the float errors in your original attempt aren't necessarily a problem *at all*. An error of 10<sup>-9</sup> in a real-world measured quantity is for all meaningful purposes neglectable. If you need something to be truely exact, you probably shouldn't be using fractional values *at all*, but straight integers. So, conside Carl's suggestion of just living with the float-deviations, but simply *printing* them in a suitably rounded form, by way of [`showFFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showFFloat), [`printf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf), or [`Text.Show.Pragmatic.print`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pragmatic-show-0.1.2.1/docs/Text-Show-Pragmatic.html#v:print).

---

<sup>★</sup><sub>Actually, in this specific case both solutions are almost equivalent, because converting `Rational` to float involves floating-point dividing the numerator by the denominator.</sub>

### Answer to your module-loading problem

In cases where you do need the [`Decimal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Decimal-0.5.1) library (or some other library), you need to *depend* on it.

- The easiest way to do this is to use [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) and add `Decimal` to your *global project*. Then, you can load the file with `stack ghci` and it'll know where to look for `Data.Decimal`.
- Alternatively, and IMO preferrably, you should create a *project package* yourself and only make that depend on `Decimal`. This can be done with either Stack or [Cabal-install](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/).

  ```
  $ mkdir my-decimal-project
  $ cd my-decimal-project
  $ cabal init
  ```

  Now you're being asked some questions about the name etc. of your project, you can mostly answer with the defaults. Say your project defines a *library* (you can add an executable later on if you want.)

  `cabal init` creates amongst other things a `my-decimal-project.cabal` file. In that file, add `Decimal` to the dependency, and your own source file to `exposed-modules`.

  Then you need to (still in your project directory) `cabal install --dependencies-only` to fetch the `Decimal` library, and then `cabal repl` to load your module.

Comment: "in rational arithmetic ... you need to carry an ever-growing range of precision through the entire calculation" *unless* we work in fixed precision by applying `x2 = approxRational x1 (1 % 10^p)` after each operation, with `p = 10 * finalDigitsNeeded`, say. will take care of memory and run faster, too. (if we're unsure about the `10 *` factor, we can run the second time with `20 *` and see if it changes anything...).  --- also, why your first snippet is working and how, and why the next one isn't? the answer would sure benefit from some explanations there... :)

Comment: @WillNess using `Rational` for fixed-precision is questionable. Use a dedicated type instead.

Comment: ah, yes, that makes sense, as a sound programming practice. I was focusing more on the essence of it.

Comment: So there's no way to load `Data.Decimal` at the ghci REPl command line?

Comment: @147pm There is -- after following the steps described in leftaroundabout's answer, `cabal repl` (or `stack ghci`) will start GHCi with an environment in which the *Decimal* package is available.

Comment: I think there's a decent argument that range notation for non-integer numbers in general is broken because it arises from `instance Enum Float` that probably shouldn't exist. Yes, you _can technically_ enumerate all of the values representable by a `Float`, but it's functionally useless to do so.

Comment: @AndrewRay yes, it's one of the instances that I wish _were not implemented_. In fact I'd even argue that conceptually, `Float` can't be enumerated _at all_ because it represents ℝ (whereas `Rational` represents ℚ, which _is_ countable).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Even `Enum Rational` annoys me because even though you can enumerate ℚ, there is no enumeration that guarantees that items enumerated later are greater than those enumerated earlier, which means there's no satisfying definition for `succ` and `pred`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout There's a difference between "`approxRational` after every calculation" and "use fixed-precision everywhere": `Rational` can represent repeating decimals (or whatever base) cleanly. To be able to represent all the same numbers as `Rational`s with a denominator no bigger than 10^p, your fixed precision denominator would have to be something like `lcm [1, ..., 10^p]`, which seems likely to be quite large!

Comment: @duplode Well, I mean without attaching the REPL to any project. Even if this loading of Decimal had to be done outside the ghci REPL at, e.g., a bash command line, it would be preferable from using the "project" system. I'm actually using Emacs org-mode Babel code blocks, and I'd rather avoid projects. I came from the Scheme/geiser world where you can totally live in the org-mode Babel/interactive REPL world.

Comment: @147pm “no project” is just a poor man's way of having _a single project_ which is the only one you ever use. As I explained, Stack actually has a _global project_ which is just that. But local project also are just as good, and have some additional advantages.

Comment: @147pm `cabal repl --build-depends=Decimal` should give you a REPL with no need for any preceding configuration. That said, packages are how Haskell code in general is organised, and odds are you'll want to use them as your code base begins to grow and take shape. Ideally, the Haskell tooling in org-mode/Babel (an environment I'm not at all familiar with) would provide integration with cabal-install and/or Stack, which would be no different to how, for instance, it offers [Leiningen integration for Clojure](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-clojure.html).

Comment: @duplode I'm in stack. `cabal repl --build-depends=Decimal` gives `Command 'cabal' not found, but can be installed with:`sudo apt install cabal-install`. I'm sure that's not what I want to do.

Comment: @leftaroundabout What exactly is the stack "global project"? I have in my home directory a `.stack` directory. Inside there is a `config.yaml`. Is this where I should do something to include `Decimal`? Again, the org-mode Babel model is "global" REPL-oriented.

Comment: FYI: In every Haskell beginner book I've ever seen, they have you stick Haskell code in a text file, fire up a ghci REPL at the command line, and :load the text file. Not once have I found anybody who walks you through a Stack or cabal project setup. The org-mode Babel for Haskell is basically the same deal, albeit buggy and barebones.

Comment: `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`. Therein you can either list `extra-deps` (which need to be exact hashes of concrete versions, e.g. `Decimal-0.5.1-Dlj8tsawcugHwOaxSTfZEt`), or you can put an ordinary Cabal project into the folder (e.g. `~/.stack/global-project/myGlobalProject` with a `myGlobalProject.cabal` that lists `Decimal` in its `build-depends`. Then the `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml` just needs to specify a Stackage snapshot (e.g. `resolver: lts-13.25`) and `packages: [myGlobalProject]`.

Comment: ...Or, analogous to `cabal repl --build-depends=Decimal`, you can also just launch your REPL with `stack ghci --package Decimal`.

Comment: @147pm (1) As leftaroundabout says, if you are using Stack `stack ghci --package Decimal` is the equivalent of the command I suggested. (2) Beginner books sometimes make the dubious assumption that beginners won't need libraries other than those that come with GHC, though such a misstep is less common in the more recent ones. A contributing factor is that the first release of Stack is from mid-2015 (which is fairly recent in the time scale of textbooks), and before that cabal-install used to be a lot less user-friendly than it is now.

Comment: @DanielWagner it was I that used the term "fixed precision", and in imprecise ( / incorrect / ) fashion. I meant it as I've described it, for the repeated `approxRational ... (1 % 10^p)` operation, not as its usual meaning of values with `p` decimal digits after the decimal point. sorry for any confusion. I took the author's suggestion of a dedicated type to mean a `Rational` value packaged up with its `p` value, which would always perform the `approxRational` operation after a true `Rational`-based calculation for us, behind the scenes. a better term could be, maybe, "capped precision"?

Comment: @duplode I don't really understand how Stack and cabal work together. Aren't they completely different project management systems for Haskell? Or do they complement and work together?

Comment: @147pm Stack and cabal-install are independent frontends to the same build system (which, rather confusingly, is also called Cabal). Though you only need one of them for package management, they don't interfere with each other, and so you can have and use them both if you want, even in the same project.

Comment: @duplode Great to know! A `which` produced no `cabal` on my system, so may I install Cabal and it won't hose (fight with) my Stack?

Comment: @147pm Yup, Stack won't be affected. On a separate note, I recommend making sure your distro offers cabal-install 3 or above; if not, you're better off installing it through [ghcup](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/). (It won't interfere with Stack either way; it's just that cabal-install 3 has large advantages in usability over earlier versions.)

Answer (score 3):

**Note**

This answer is an FYI for all of you beginners simply trying to follow along in a beginner Haskell book that has you typing code into a text editor, firing up the ghci REPL and doing `:load my-haskell-code.hs`.

**YMMV Solution**

As can be gleaned above, `Data.Decimal` is not a standard included Prelude sort of package. It must be loaded independently -- and no, it doesn't work to simply put `import Data.Decimal` at the top of your code. As `leftaroundabout` said in a comment above, the very simplest way for Haskell beginners not yet doing projects is to start ghci thusly

```
stack ghci --package Decimal
```

Of course YMMV depending on how you installed Haskell. I installed Haskell through the stack project management, hence, the `stack` before `ghci --package Decimal`. Another unique thing about my setup is I'm using Emacs org-mode's Babel code blocks, which is largely the same as the basic type-and-load way, i.e., non-project. I did try to alter Emacs's `haskell-process-args-stack-ghci` which is in `haskell-customize.el` by just adding `--package Decimal` but it didn't work. Instead, I simply went to my bash command line and put in `stack ghci --package Decimal`, then I restarted a separate org-mode Babel ghci and it worked. Now,

```
dList :: [Decimal]
dList = [1.00,1.01..2.00]

> dList
[1,1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05,1.06,1.07,1.08,1.09,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.17,1.18,1.19,1.20,1.21,1.22,1.23,1.24,1.25,1.26,1.27,1.28,1.29,1.30,1.31,1.32,1.33,1.34,1.35,1.36,1.37,1.38,1.39,1.40,1.41,1.42,1.43,1.44,1.45,1.46,1.47,1.48,1.49,1.50,1.51,1.52,1.53,1.54,1.55,1.56,1.57,1.58,1.59,1.60,1.61,1.62,1.63,1.64,1.65,1.66,1.67,1.68,1.69,1.70,1.71,1.72,1.73,1.74,1.75,1.76,1.77,1.78,1.79,1.80,1.81,1.82,1.83,1.84,1.85,1.86,1.87,1.88,1.89,1.90,1.91,1.92,1.93,1.94,1.95,1.96,1.97,1.98,1.99,2.00]
```

no muss, no fuss. I killed the ghci and loaded it without the `--package Decimal` and it still knew about `Decimal`, so this change is recorded quasi-permanently in my `~/.stack` directory somewhere? Oddly, the bash ghci session doesn't know about the `*haskell*` ghci session in org-mode. Also, when just using the Emacs haskell mode stand-alone for type-and-load, its ghci session also doesn't play well with the org-mode ghci. I've gone with the minimalist Emacs org-mode babel because it seems better than just `lhs` literal Haskell. If anyone knows how to make literal Haskell sing like org-mode, I'd like to know.

**Postmortem**

I guess I insisted on figuring out `Decimal` because in researching the whole rounding issue I started seeing a wild divergence of suggested solutions (not necessarily here, but other places) and scary technical arguments. `Decimal` seemed the simplest in a wild storm of competing rounding strategies. Rounding should be simple, but in Haskell it turned into a time-sucking trip down multiple rabbit holes.